# Why is my alert not being displayed on success call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to work out why my alert in the 'function processResponse(data)' part of the code, is not being displayed. I have tried various return; options, but still, refuses to display.

I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks.

**PS.** I am aware of security issues in the code posted such as mysql_escape_string, but all security issues will be inserted before the site goes live.

jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $('#srcsubmit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#srcBox').val() == '') {

            notif({
                type: "error",
                msg: "<b>ERROR:<br /><br />You must enter a search term</b><p>Click anywhere to close</p>",
                height: 99,
                multiline: true,
                position: "middle,center",
                fade: true,
                timeout: 3000

            });
            return false;
        }

        $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#submit2").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#submit3").prop("disabled", true);
        var value = $('#srcBox').val();
        var dept = '<?php echo $_GET['dept ']; ?>';

        var qString = 'sub=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&dept=' + encodeURIComponent(dept);

        $.post('sub_db_handler.php', qString, processResponse);
    });

    function processResponse(data) {
        if (data === 'true') {

            alert('That box is not on the system'); <--- this is the problem
            return;
        }

        $('#srcBoxRslt').val(data);
    };
});


</script>
```

PHP backend

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
    mysql_select_db("sample", $con);

    $dept = trim($_POST['dept']);
    $custref = trim($_POST['sub']);



    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boxes WHERE custref = '".$custref."'");
    $found = mysql_num_rows($result);

     if ($found == 0)
        {
            echo trim('true');

        } else {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM boxes WHERE department = '".$dept."' AND status = 1 AND custref = '".$custref."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
    $r = $row['custref'];

    $str =  json_encode($r);
    echo trim($str, '"');

    }


        ?>
```

Comment: it means `data is not equal true`

Comment: Open developers console and check errors, see raw output

Comment: @guradio In firebug respone tab show true

Comment: @u_mulder I don't use chrome. Use firefox

Comment: @user1532468 then there must be a space somewhere data `.trim()` data and try

Comment: And what? Firefox has developers console __too__

Comment: try console.log in if statement . see if data is true in if condition

Comment: @webpic I did console.log(data); in if statement but shows nothing. But the response tab shows ;true'; How do I trim the data. I have trimmed from php so shouldn't any space be removed. thanks

Comment: simplest test is to create an `else` statement and put an alert there too

Comment: `data.trim()` in js

Comment: @A.lau  I did that and it alerted true. It shouldn't have got that far. return; should have halted execution?

Comment: @user1532468 it means data is not equal to `true` so it went to else part go trim your data see what happens

Comment: @guradio that was it. if you would like to post as answer, I will gladly mark up. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data value is not equal to `true` because of extra space to get rid of extra use `.trim()`

Comment: Thank you very much